# Ansible: How to run particular host in Vagrant?

Tags: ansible, ansible-inventory

I have a complex Ansible setup with several hosts in my group file. Something like this.

```
# hosts/groups

[local]
127.0.0.1

[server1]
server1.domain.com

[server2]
server2.domain.com

[group1]
local
server1

[group2]
local
server2
```

This way, I can run both groups against localhost:2222 which is my Vagrant box, however, they will be both executed. For testing I would very much prefer to choose, which setting, I would like to test. I have experimented with --extra-vars arguments and conditionals, which is pretty ugly. Is there a way to use the extra_vars argument with the host configuration. Using a command like ...

```
ansible-playbook playbook.yml -i hosts -l 127.0.0.1:2222 --extra-vars "vhost=server1.domain.com"
```

Or am I entirely wrong.

Comment: I'm not quite sure what you're trying to do.  You want to run the same playbooks against your local development machine as your production hosts?

Comment: Sorry for being unclear, I have a production setup with quite a few (mostly unrelated) machines. While creating another one, I would like to run only this particular machine against my vagrant instance to see how things are going.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "run only this particular machine against my vagrant instance"; do you mean you only want to run a particular *role* or *playbook* against your vagrant instance?

Comment: To be precise, all playbook entries/roles that are assigned to a host definition. Basically, to have a copy of the host machine in vagrant. Given the example above, I would like to get the operations performed on group1 but not the once of group2, which would happen in the example above. But maybe I am entirely wrong.

Comment: Oh, I understand - your local machine simulates multiple types of servers (`server1` and `server2`), and you want to test only *one* of those types against it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think there's an easy way to do this via alterations to how you executes Ansible.

The best option I can think of involves potentially re-organizing your playbooks.  If you create `group1.yaml` and `group2.yaml`, each containing the statements necessary for setting up `group1` and `group2`, respectively, then you can run something like

```
[$]> ansible-playbook -l 127.0.0.1:2222 group1.yaml
```

to only run the `group1` configuration against your development instance.

If you still want a convenient way to run all tasks, alter your `playbook.yaml` to include the other playbooks:

```
- include: group1.yaml
- include: group2.yaml
```